# jquery mobile - loading spin wheel keep appearing

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jquerymobile latest stable version with jquery 1.5

on my application i am using Spring webflow,

On first page of flow i have two links to other pages. See below scenario

- Click on link 1
- Page B opens with slide transition
- click browser back button
- First page comes back but with spin wheel which never disappear

How to get rid from this spin wheel?

This is happening in android and iphone

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery Core 1.6.4? It's the jQuery Core that all but the latest (unstable) versions of jQuery Mobile support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the version of jQuery Mobile you are using, you may have to upgrade your jQuery Core.

As of the Beta  2, this was stated:

> Note that jQuery Mobile 1.0 will require jQuery core 1.6.2 as a
>   baseline.

From: http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/08/03/jquery-mobile-beta-2-released/

**UPDATE**

According to the Release page for 1.0.1, they use 1.6.4.  I believe this is the minimum and 1.0.1 is the latest full release of jQM as of this writing.

http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/01/26/jquery-mobile-1-0-1-released/

Comment: Is this jquery version backward compatible?

Comment: I'm sorry but that would not be possible for me to answer without knowing your code base.  It probably is, but you'd have to test it to be sure. Or, checkout the release information talking about the differences here - http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/

Comment: I switched to jq1.6.4 now with jqm1.0.1.  During transition the spin wheel is coming but grays shade is not coming. what can be reason?

Comment: I don't completely understand the problem anymore.  Maybe try `$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();`  What does 'grays shade is not coming' mean?